# php - PDO update mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wish to update a field in my database, to the current value, plus another value.

For some reason, below code doesn't work - although I don't receive any PHP error:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET rbalance=rbalance+':amount', alertpay_invest=alertpay_invest+':amount' WHERE id=':userid'"); //Works
                    $stmt->bindParam(':amount', $amount);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $itemType[0]);
                    $stmt->execute();
```

Can someone please help me?

I am new to PDO, and I don't know how to enable error debugging either..

Comment: there is no need to wrap in quotes flags (`:amount` etc.)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I can't stop noticing your negative attitude towards everyone all over the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
  rbalance=rbalance+':amount'
```

by

```
 rbalance=rbalance+ :amount
```

you are adding `int` with `string`

and this

```
   alertpay_invest=alertpay_invest+':amount'
```

to

```
  alertpay_invest=alertpay_invest+ :amount
```

whole query:

```
 UPDATE users SET rbalance=rbalance+ :amount , 
                  alertpay_invest=alertpay_invest+ :amount  
 WHERE id= :userid
```